# How to check if Session is alive with firebase + react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've added an authorization with firebase, which works completely fine.
It is possible to login to the app, and navigate, but when I use `firebase.auth().signOut` the `onAuthChanged` observable is not changed/not triggered.

For correct login/password(400 for the wrong combination) - the session is saved, and I have the user credentials:

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import {ROUTES} from '../../../constants';
import {AuthUserContext} from "../../../session";
import history from '../../../helpers/history';
import {useLocation} from "react-router";
import app from "../../../api/firebase";

const WithAuthorization: React.FC = ({children}) => {
    const authUser = useContext(AuthUserContext);
    const isLogin = useLocation().pathname === ROUTES.LOGIN;
    const pushLogin = () => !isLogin && history.push(ROUTES.LOGIN);

    useEffect(() => {
        const listener = app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(
            (user: any) => {
                if(!user) {
                    pushLogin()
                } else {
                    console.log('Signed in with user');
                    console.log(user);
                }
            },
            (e: any) => {
                console.log(e);
            }, () => {
                console.log('completed');
            });
        return listener();
    }, [])

    return <>
        {authUser ? children : pushLogin()}
    </>;
}

export default WithAuthorization;
```

But then, when the application is refreshed, I want to check if the session is alive.
While looking through the docs I've found [onAuthChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) observable, which seems pretty straight-forward, but it is actually triggered only when I log in.

After the page is refreshed, or when I trigger `signOut` - it does nothing.

This is the authorization protection component, that wraps the entire App:

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import {ROUTES} from '../../../constants';
import {AuthUserContext} from "../../../session";
import history from '../../../helpers/history';
import app from "../../../api/firebase";

const WithAuthorization: React.FC = ({children}) => {
    const authUser = useContext(AuthUserContext);
    const pushLogin = () => history.push(ROUTES.LOGIN);

    useEffect(() => {
        const listener = app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(
            (user: any) => {
                if(!user) pushLogin()
            },
            (e: any) => {
                console.log(e);
            }, () => {
                console.log('completed');
            });
        return listener();
    }, [])

    return <>
        {authUser ? children : pushLogin()}
    </>;
}

export default WithAuthorization;
```

Am I missing something with the auth protection component or observable?

--- The app structure:

The App component is quite simple:

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
    import { Route, Switch, useLocation } from 'react-router';
    import { Header, WithAuthorization } from './common';
    import DeviceSelection from './DeviceSelection';
    import PerfectScroll from 'react-perfect-scrollbar';
    import NotFound from './NotFound';
    import ThankYou from "./Thankyou";
    
    import 'react-perfect-scrollbar/dist/css/styles.css';
    import './App.scss';
    import {ROUTES} from "../constants";
    import Login from "./Login";
    import {AuthUserContext} from "../session";
    
    const App = () => {
        const {pathname} = useLocation();
        const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState(null as any);
        const isThankYou = pathname === ROUTES.THANKYOU;
    
        return (
            <AuthUserContext.Provider
                value={authUser}
            >
                <WithAuthorization>
                    {!isThankYou && <Header authUser={authUser}/>}
                </WithAuthorization>
    
                    <div className={`${!isThankYou ? 'appScrollContainer' : ''}`}>
                        <PerfectScroll>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route exact path={[ROUTES.ROOT, ROUTES.HOME]} component={() => <WithAuthorization><DeviceSelection/></WithAuthorization>} />
                                <Route path={ROUTES.THANKYOU} component={() => <WithAuthorization><ThankYou/></WithAuthorization>} />
                                <Route path={ROUTES.LOGIN} component={() => <Login setAuthUser={(user: any) => setAuthUser(user)} />}/>
                                <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
                            </Switch>
                        </PerfectScroll>
                    </div>
            </AuthUserContext.Provider>
        );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Signout is coming from a button, inside Header, which is also wrapped in WithAuthorization:

```
    <Button label={'Sign out'} click={() => app.auth().signOut()} />
```

Login does only one 1 thing, redirects to /home if login was successful:

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
    import TextInput from "../common/TextInput";
    import history from '../../helpers/history';
    import {ROUTES} from "../../constants";
    import app, {signInWithEmailAndPassword} from "../../api/firebase";
    
    interface Props {
        setAuthUser: (user: any) => void,
    }
    
    const Login: React.FC<Props> = ({setAuthUser}) => {
        const [form, updateForm] = useState({login: '', password: ''});
    
        const authorize = (user: string, password: string) => {
            app.auth().setPersistence(app.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
                .then(() => {
                    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(user, password).then((user: any) => {
                        if(user) {
                            setAuthUser(user);
                            history.push(ROUTES.ROOT);
                            return user
                        }
                        return null
                    })
                })
                .catch((e: any) => {
                    console.log(e);
                })
        }
    
        return <div className='form'>
            <TextInput
                type="text"
                placeholder='login'
                name={'login'}
                value={form.login}
                label='Login'
                onChange={(e) => updateForm({...form, login: e.currentTarget.value})}
            />
            <TextInput
                type="password"
                placeholder='password'
                name={'password'}
                value={form.password}
                label='Password'
                onChange={(e) => updateForm({...form, password: e.currentTarget.value})}
            />
            <button onClick={() => authorize(form.login, form.password)}>Submit</button>
        </div>
    }
    
    export default Login;
```

FIrebase usage itself:

```
    import firebase from 'firebase/app';
    import 'firebase/firestore';
    import 'firebase/auth';
    
    import {DEV_LOCAL_CONFIG, DEV_REMOTE_CONFIG, ORDERS_COLLECTION} from "./const";
    
    firebase.initializeApp(window.location.hostname !== 'localhost' ? DEV_LOCAL_CONFIG : DEV_REMOTE_CONFIG);
    
    /* ==== Authorization ==== */
    const signInWithEmailAndPassword = (email: string, password: string) =>
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    
    const signOut = () => firebase.auth().signOut();
    
    export default firebase;
    
    export {
        signInWithEmailAndPassword,
        signOut
    }
```

Comment: It will trigger on both signin and signout.  How are you observing that it doesn't work for signout?  Please edit the question to provide the full steps and code for that.

Comment: That is true, I'm trying to make signOut trigger the onAuthChanged, but even that is not happening. Will update the question.

Comment: @DougStevenson, I've added the app structure. Not even sure if there is a place for the mistake, but the result speaks for itself.

Comment: I've just noticed that when I do signOut - the session gets deleted, but the function is still not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was with this line only:

```
return listener();
```

When I define listener in `useEffect`, it is unsubscribed immediately.
Should be:

```
return () => listener()
```

Other than this, everything works fine.